# Spark create dataframe in IDE (using databricks-connect)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm attempting to run some code from my databricks notebook in an IDE using databrick connect. I can't seem to figure out how to create a simple dataframe.

Using:

```
import spark.implicits._

var Table_Count = Seq((cdpos_df.count(),I_count,D_count,U_count)).toDF("Table_Count","I_Count","D_Count","U_Count")
```

gives the error message `value toDF is not a member of Seq[(Long, Long, Long, Long)]`.

Trying to create the dataframe from scratch:

```
var dataRow = Seq((cdpos_df.count(),I_count,D_count,U_count))

    var schemaRow = List(
      StructField("Table_Count", LongType, true),
      StructField("I_Count", LongType, true),
      StructField("D_Count", LongType, true),
      StructField("U_Count", LongType, true)
    )

    var TableCount = spark.createDataFrame(
      sc.parallelize(dataRow),
      StructType(schemaRow)
    )
```

Gives the error message

```
overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  (data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Long, Long, Long)], org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the methods using:

```
var TableCount = spark.createDataFrame(
      sc.parallelize(dataRow)
      // StructType(schemaRow)
          ).toDF("Table_Count","I_Count","D_Count","U_Count")
```

gets rid of the errors but I still need to build this in a bit...